# How to use viewmodel + room with fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm

I'm looking through the tutorial for [Android room with a view](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#15), and trying to extend their model for using `ViewModels` to multiple fragments, but not really sure how.

**MyApplication**

```
class myApplication : Application() {


    companion object {
        var database: myDatabase? = null
        var repository: myRepository? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        database = MyDatabase.getInstance(this)
        repository = MyRepository(database!!.myDatabaseDao)

    }
}
```

**MyViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel(private val repository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {


    val allWords: LiveData<List<Words>> = repository.allWords.asLiveData()

    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(word)
    }
}

class MyViewModelFactory(private val repository: MyRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MyViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        myViewModel.allWords.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { words ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words.let { Log.d("fragment", it.toString()) }
        }

    }
}
```

I have a couple of other fragments that will hopefully share the same `ViewModel` as `HomeFragment`. I've tried many different approaches, such as using

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

but all of them give me `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.tabtester.ViewModels.MyViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`. I can't find any SO posts or documentation that shows me how to provide a constructor in Kotlin.

Also conceptually I can't find any description for what exactly is happening and how the viewmodel is being constructed (and by what). In the Room with a View tutorial, the example given is in `MainActivity`:

```
private val wordViewModel: WordViewModel by viewModels {
    WordViewModelFactory((application as WordsApplication).repository)
}
```

This makes sense, to me; you're using the Factory to instantiate a ViewModel to use in the MainActivity. But for any description of how to use ViewModels in Fragments, I don't see where the ViewModel is being constructed. If you have multiple fragments who is constructing the ViewModel? If I use Fragments then does that mean I also need an activity to construct the ViewModel, then somehow share between the Fragments?

Would appreciate any help, or documentation that explains this more clearly.

Comment: `by activityViewModels()` takes a Factory as an optional parameter. Why aren't you passing your custom factory to it?

Comment: I tried it, and throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles`.

Comment: So it sounds like you were able to get your shared ViewModel working (it is successfully creating your ViewModel now).

Comment: Well it compiled and created a ViewModel, but it's unclear that its working - I'm not sure how to actually observe my data and test if its a shared viewmodel instance across fragments.

Comment: I fixed the observer error, and it looks like it potentially works, if I add`private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels() {MyViewModelFactory(MyApplication.repository!!)}` per your suggestion! However, does this mean if I add this line to every `Fragment` class, it will be using a shared instance of `ViewModel` rather than creating new ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying APIs of `by viewModels()`, `by activityViewModels()` and the ([now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0)) `ViewModelProviders.of()` all feed into one method: the [ViewModelProvider constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore,%20androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory)):

```
ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore: ViewModelStore, factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory)
```

This constructor takes two parameters:

- The `ViewModelStore` controls the storage and scoping of the `ViewModel` you create. For example, when you use `by viewModels()` in a Fragment, it is the `Fragment` which is used as the `ViewModelStore`. Similarly, `by activityViewModels()` uses the `Activity` as the `ViewModelStore`.
- The `ViewModelProvider.Factory` controls the construction of the `ViewModel` if one has not already been created for that particular `ViewModelStore`.

Therefore if you need a custom `Factory`, you must **always** pass that Factory into all places that could create that `ViewModel` (remember, due to process death and recreation, there's no guarantee that your `HomeFragment` will be the first fragment to create your `ViewModel`).

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels() {
    MyViewModelFactory(MyApplication.repository!!)
}
```

As long as you're using `activityViewModels()`, the storage of your `ViewModel` will always be at the activity level, no matter what Factory you are using.